# SQL query to calculate the sum of previous record in each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I would like to get the calculated field (`previous balance` which equal to (sum of all the previous `debit`) - (sum of all previous `credit`))  in each row

for example :

for ID =5   , i want to get the previous balance of this record = (sum of debit amount) - (sum of credit amount) from ID=1 to ID =4

any suggestion please ? 
i tried the `LAG` function but still didn't get what i want 
thank you

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Hi, please provide some ddl like table structure , sample data and your query and excepted output.

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried.

Comment: i  already post an image for what I  exactly want  . hope you understand   my idea.

Comment: @HasanDhainy take look at answer and let me know if it's respond to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if i understand your wall query and if you have SQL Server version greater or equal than 2008 you can use this query example  ::

```
Create table #tblVal
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Val int
)
--Inserting Records--
Insert into #tblVal values(720)
Insert into #tblVal values(720)
Insert into #tblVal values(500)
Insert into #tblVal values(720)
Insert into #tblVal values(539)
Insert into #tblVal values(341)



select * from #tblVal

SELECT *, SUM(Val) OVER(ORDER BY Id Asc
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - Val as 'TotalSumPrevious',
     SUM(Val) OVER(ORDER BY Id Asc
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'TotalSumCurrent'
FROM #tblVal 

drop table #tblVal
```

AND take look at this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Code edit with example picture :

```
Create table #tblVal
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Debit int,
Credit int
)
--Inserting Records--
Insert into #tblVal values(10,0)
Insert into #tblVal values(0,5)
Insert into #tblVal values(20,0)
Insert into #tblVal values(0,30)
Insert into #tblVal values(10,0)
Insert into #tblVal values(0,30)
Insert into #tblVal values(10,0)



select * from #tblVal

SELECT *, 
     SUM(Debit - Credit)  OVER(ORDER BY Id Asc
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - (Debit - Credit) as 'PreviousBalance'
FROM #tblVal 

drop table #tblVal
```

Comment: thank you very much . yeah this is what i want exactly . have a good day

Comment: @HasanDhainy glad to help you. Good day too.